# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux}{2\sigma^{2}}}du$?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, fourier-transform

As part of an exercise in Fourier transforms, I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux}{2\sigma^{2}}}du
$$
The exercise is to prove that for the the following Fourier transform:
$$
\hat{f}(u,v)=\exp\left(-\frac{u^{2}+v^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)
$$

we get:
$$
f(x,y)=2\pi\sigma^{2}\exp\left(-2\pi^{2}\sigma^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\right)
$$

In my textbook they did:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux}{2\sigma^{2}}}du&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux+\left(4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}-4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}\right)}{2\sigma^{2}}}du=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux-4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{\frac{4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du\\&=e^{\frac{4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux-4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du=e^{\frac{4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-2u\left(i2\sigma^{2}\pi x\right)+\left(i2\sigma^{2}\pi x\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du\\&=e^{\frac{4\pi^{2}x^{2}\sigma^{4}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\left(u-i2\sigma^{2}\pi x\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du
\end{align*}
$$
Then they stated that because of the normal distribution, you get:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\left(u-i2\sigma^{2}\pi x\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du=\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}
$$
I don't quite understand why. First of all, as I understand that, they stated that $U\sim N\left(i2\sigma^{2}\pi x,\sigma\right)$, but can $\mu$ (the first argument) be a non-real value? Secondly, how did they got to $\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$?

If someone is interested in the original exercise, then they did:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(u,v)e^{i2\pi(ux+vy)}dudv=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{v^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{i2\pi ux}e^{i2\pi vy}dudv\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{i2\pi ux}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{v^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}e^{i2\pi vy}dudv=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}+i2\pi ux}du\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{v^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}+i2\pi vy}dv\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux}{2\sigma^{2}}}du\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{v^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi vy}{2\sigma^{2}}}dv
\end{align*}
$$
Then they started talking about $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^{2}-i4\sigma^{2}\pi ux}{2\sigma^{2}}}du$ (where I got stuck).

Comment: What happened to $x$ in your integrals? You got $\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}$ on the right hand side, but there is still an $x$ in the left hand side?

Comment: Suppose U is normal distributed with mean $a$, then $\frac{1}{\sigma \cdot \sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\left(u-a \right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du=1\Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\left(u-a \right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du=\sigma \cdot \sqrt{2\pi}$ $\ a$ is an arbritrary constant.

Comment: @callculus42 right, but can the mean be non-real value?

Comment: Shifting the contour might help here. Let $z=u-i2\sigma^2\pi x$ and perform substitution. This will yield integration over a horizontal line in the complex plane. Consider $\int_\Gamma \exp(-z^2/(2\sigma^2))\,\mathrm{d}z$ over $\Gamma = \partial \Omega, \Omega = [-R,R]\times i[0,2\sigma^2\pi x].$ The integral over $\Gamma$ is zero by Cauchy theorem and you just need to show that the integral over the vertical lines tend to zero as $R\to \infty$ which can be done by some standard estimation.